# iPhone - how to reference textboxes in container

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a UIViewController that has a Container inside of it. The view inside the Container is a UITableViewController with a Static Table. It has two textboxes inside of it. I would like to reference the textboxes the same way I would if they were in the parent view. Meaning I'd like to setup the parent to be a delegate of the text boxes. Is there a way to do this easily?

Comment: Consider `tag` property for UI element; It may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the piece I was missing was to use the segue to set a reference to the container's view controller (which needs to be custom and have the elements you want to reference defined in the .h as outlets.

So to summarize:

- Create a custom view controller
- Drag the elements you want to reference to that custom view controller's .h file
- Use the prepareForSegue method to set a reference to your container's view controller
- In your viewDidAppear method set delegates just like you would items in your parent view controller.